# Sed creating duplicates

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have used the command sed in shell to remove everything except for numbers from my string.

Now, my string contains three 0s among other numbers and after running

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
```

Instead of three 0s, i now have 0 01 and 02.

How can I prevent sed from doing that so that I can have the three 0s?

sample of the string:

```
0      cat
42     dog 
24     fish
0      bird
0      tiger
5      fly
```

Comment: can you provide an input string sample?

Comment: Updated the post. Image number and animal next to it in a column.

Comment: so you want to keep only zeroes?

Comment: No I want all the numbers with zero being there three times, not 0 01 and 02 which is what I'm getting atm.

Comment: what is your expected output for the specified sample?

Comment: Are you sure the sed command produces 0 01 02 when run on the given input? It works for me.

Comment: are you piping in from another command? I see no way you could be getting `0` `01` `02` from that input ...

Comment: My expected output would be 0 42 24 0 0 5 in the string above and yes it really does that. I am using the du -a command to get size of files, then I remove all the text by running sed but it creates duplicate zeros.

Comment: @Daeto, what is your goal? what do you want to do with the list of numbers? PS your `sed` snippet works for me as well when piping output from `du -a`

Comment: How bizarre ... your actual sed snippet on my system gives exactly the desired (and expected) result. Did you tack an extra 'p' on to your sed you're running? :)

Comment: I think it might be because the input to sed is like this: du -a "$var" | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'

Comment: @Daeto, It's really strange - `du -a "$var" | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'` works absolutely as expected for me. How did you set `$var`?

Comment: @Daeto I believe some of your filenames have a digit in the filename, like cat2.  So the 0 is from the size and the mysterious numbers after the 0 are from the filename. Please show output of `ls "$var"` or `du -a "$var"`.

Comment: Oh yes! This is it! So I need to figure out how to exclude numbers that are preceded or followed by anything other than blank space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that we know that digits in filenames in the output from the `du` utility caused the problem (tip of the hat to [Lars Fischer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4086774/lars-fischer)), simply use `cut` to extract only first column (which contains the data of interest, each file's/subdir.'s size in blocks):

```
 du -a "$var" | cut -f1
```

`du` outputs tab-separated data, and a tab is also `cut`'s default separator, so all that is needed is to ask for the 1st field (`-f1`).

---

In hindsight, your problem was unrelated to `sed`; your sample data simply wasn't representative of your actual data. It's always worth creating an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking a question.

Comment: Thanks a lot this did the trick! Silly me, I didn't realize some files had numbers in their names!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
du -a "$var" | sed -e 's/ .*//' -e 's/[^0-9]*//g'
```